# Why is my data being removed when i update a certain field in a realtime database in flutter for web

Tags: flutter, http, dart, firebase-realtime-database, web-applications

I am trying to update my data in the real-time database in flutter for a web app. But whenever I update my data, it deletes all of the other fields in the same table.

```
ChangeNotificationStatus() async {
    Map NotificationData = {
      "NotificationChecked": "YES",
    };
    await put(
        Uri.parse(
            "https://officialnasproject-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/App/Notification.json"),
        body: jsonEncode(NotificationData));
  }
```

[image: Database Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you `put` data to a path in the database, the data you provide in the request replaces all existing data in that path.

If you want to only update a single property, you can two options:

- You can `put` that single value to the lower level path:

  ```
  await put(
    Uri.parse(
      "https://officialnasproject-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/App/Notification/NotificationChecked.json"),
    body: jsonEncode("YES"));
  }
  ```
- You can use `patch`, which replaces only the keys you have in your `NotificationData` map and leaves other keys unmodified.

For more on these operations, I recommend reading the Firebase documentation on the [REST API of the Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data).